# Cut a string recursively

Tags: php, html, string

I have a string, and I must print it in a div.

The width of the div is limited, so if many characters are close the string will exit from the div.

Just think to a `width:30px` div and a string such as `hellomynameismarcoandilikemadewebapplicationinmyfreetimes`.

So I need a sort of function on php that cut recursively the string; I mean, cut the string and add somethings like `<br/>`.

Another problem here is that my string is printed through `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");` , so the `<br/>` will fail.

How can I do it on PHP?

**EDIT** My Final Solution

```
function printMyStrings($str, $width) {
    return ereg_replace("&lt;br/&gt;","<br/>", htmlentities(wordwrap($str, $width, "<br/>", true), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: This isn't what "recursive" means, by the way. You just want to cut a string to a certain length, run it through the `htmlentities()`, then append `</br>`. I'd write a proper answer but I don't know how to do the first step in PHP (although I'm sure it's drop-dead simple).

Comment: The problem is knowing the exact width your text will take up. Each browser and each user will have it rendered differently

Comment: @Dutchie432 yes, but I can evalutate this more or less :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will hard-wrap it at `$width`.  [Docs on `wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$width = 30;
$wrapped_string = wordwrap("Hellomynameismarcoandilikemadewebapplicationinmyfreetimes.", $width, "\n", TRUE);

// nl2br to add HTML linebreaks
echo nl2br($wrapped_string);
```

Comment: Yeah, this should rock! Expect the fact that nl2br won't work : I'm into htmlentities(), but as @ariel suggest I just put a space instead of <br/> or \n :)

Comment: Sorry - I misread thinking your string had *already* been through `htmlentites()`, rather than it was being filtered there next.

Comment: @kwichz Looks good. Just a note that the `ereg()` family is deprecated and will go away in PHP6.  They should be replaced in `preg_replace()`

Comment: Uhm : so how can I change it with that function? I thought preg_replace() was only for regex :)

Comment: @kwichz it is for regex, but your regex doesn't have to be complicated. `ereg` was for regex too. Actually in this case you can just use `str_replace()`. It's a drop-in replacement for `ereg_replace()` in this case.

Comment: `return str_replace("&lt;br/&gt;","<br/>", htmlentities(wordwrap($str, $width, "<br/>", true), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));`

Answer (score 3):

```
chunk_split ( $string , 80 ,"<br>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a space and the browser will take care of breaking it for you